# Apply an image to the loading bar

Tags: c#

I develop a program (*Autodownloader*) in order to update my *BackUps*.

This program has two *upload loading bars*:

- The **1st Bar** → Control the files for download.
- The **2nd Bar** → Actual download the files.

These bars have to have their own *system graphics*. 
I would like to put my own graphics, such as the ones that used in some games.

Do you have any suggestions or any advice for this matter?

**Example of how it looks like:**

[image]

**Example of what I would like it to look like:**

[image]

> I don't think that there is any code to show you as they are the simple bars which are already be defined by the VisualStudio toolbox.

In case you have specific questions about the code, I will update the post very quickly.

Comment: use correct tags...and read [ask].

Comment: some [TAG] asks me about the reputation to include them. As for my way of presenting the problem, I think it is quite clear !? I don't know how else to ask this question.

Comment: google: "create custom progress bar #c"

Comment: I really appreciate the way users act. I'm not the "lazy" type ... I just have no idea where to start. I followed some directions online but some codes I'm not sure are that good. I ask the most expert users for directions, I don't like everything being given to me. A link to a guide that is considered valid is also fine, so as not to have to deal with "bad code" or "bad working method". I hope I was clear, and I thank the users once again.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31906/Progress-O-Doom

Comment: What UI technology are you using? Windows Forms? WPF? UWP? Silverlight? Xamarin? We can guess, but since you're the one who created the project, and has the project, it would be far easier for you to answer the question, no? We're not asking you to do much; just show what research you've done, and any attempts you've made based on that research. Also, responding with "a link to a guide that is considered valid" would be a bad answer on Stack Overflow. We expect posts to be self-contained. See [ask] and [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided code or environment details it appears you aren't far along in your implementation. Thus, I will answer this first as an *abstract* example and then as an example of how it *could* be implemented in a *specific* environment (my example is presented in Windows Forms)

Firstly, you should understand what you are trying to accomplish. To my understanding you want a progress bar that has different data sources and the progress bars are contained inside a single container.

*Hint:Progress bars are used for notifying users' of updates in the time Axis. This means once a progress bar has been started, the completion rule of the progress bar must have already been defined. A new data source (eg. new backup, adding a second copy location) should then be displayed in a second progress bar instead of changing the completion rule for the first bar.*

*Note: The above hint is purely subjective based on my understanding of User Interface design. You could theoretically implement it a bunch of different ways. For a detailed introduction to progress bar guidelines definitely give [this article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/status-tracker-progress-update/) by the NNGroup a read*

**Design Abstraction**

You want a container of a variable height, and a mechanism to allow adding more progress bars on demand. Whether the container is blocking the calling container will depend of where the on demand functionality is based.

**Windows Forms Abstraction**

- Modular Form
- BackgroundWorker class objects, each handling a Data
  source work packet for each Progress Bar
- Synchronising the Progress
  bars with a central Authority for the Form